# Embedding counterexample

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Lee writes on page 156 of Introduction to Smooth Manifolds:

> A smooth embedding is a map that is both a topological embedding and an immersion, not just a topological embedding that happens to be smooth.

I am trying to think of a counterexample: a smooth topological embedding that fails to be an immersion. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Actually, I think $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto x^3$ might be such a counterexample.

Comment: It is one indeed.